# Web page downloader that supports redirects

Tags: c#, time-limit-exceeded, web-scraping, http

I wrote a class that downloads the HTML of a page from the internet. This class also manages redirects. This works well but I'm not very satisfied about time management for slower servers. In fact, if the website is slow, the method `GetHtml` will return an empty string, so  how can I optimize this class, to prevent such a situation from happening?

**CODE**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace SWP.Helpers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Download html from an Internet page.
    /// </summary>
    public class NetworkHelper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Store the previous url used in the request.
        /// </summary>
        private Uri _storedUrl = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Store the previous html downloaded.
        /// </summary>
        private string _storedData = "";

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the html structure of a site.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="url">Represents the URL of the page where to download the data.</param>
        /// <returns>Return a string that contains the html of the site.</returns>
        public string GetHtml(Uri url)
        {
            //If the current url is the same of the older, then will returned the previous html structure, in this way will not be wasted any time to perform another connection.
            if (url == _storedUrl)
                return _storedData;
            else
                _storedUrl = url;

            //Web request handler.
            HttpWebRequest webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            try
            {
                //Configure the client manager for perform a page compression.
                HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
                handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;

                //Handle the client to manage possible redirect.
                HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);

                //Set the web request.
                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage
                {
                    RequestUri = url,
                    Method = HttpMethod.Get
                };

                //Get the response.
                HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;

                //Return the code of the web request.
                int statusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;

                //If the code is within this range, then the server has executed a redirect.
                if (statusCode >= 300 && statusCode <= 399)
                {
                    //Get the new url.
                    Uri redirectUri = response.Headers.Location;

                    //Sanitize the url.
                    if (!redirectUri.IsAbsoluteUri)
                    {
                        redirectUri = new Uri(request.RequestUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + redirectUri);
                    }

                    //Call again this method with the correct url.
                    return GetHtml(redirectUri);
                }

                _storedData = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                return _storedData;
            }
            catch (WebException)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see, the logic is really simple, and the method is well commented. Are there any problems I haven't taken into account?

Comment: Any reason why blocking calls are being made and that the function is not async?

Comment: `HttpClientHandler` already has the ability to follow redirection responses out of the box with `AllowAutoRedirect` property

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`HttpClient` and associated classes provide most of the desired behavior.

`HttpClientHandler` already has the ability to follow redirection responses out of the box with `AllowAutoRedirect` property. You can also specify how many redirections to allow.

That can be extracted out into a function

```
static HttpMessageHandler CreateHandler() {
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    // if the framework supports redirect configuration
    // set max redirect to the desired amount. The default is 50
    if (handler.SupportsRedirectConfiguration) {
        handler.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        handler.MaxAutomaticRedirections = 5;
    }
    // if the framework supports automatic decompression 
    // set automatic decompression
    if (handler.SupportsAutomaticDecompression) {
        handler.AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.GZip |
            System.Net.DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
    }
    return handler;
}
```

Creating multiple instances of `HttpClient` can cause an exhaustion of available sockets, so it is suggested to try keeping one instance for the duration of the application.

Specify a short time out duration for slower responses to help with time management.

```
static Lazy<HttpClient> httpClient = new Lazy<HttpClient>(() => {
    var handler = CreateHandler();
    return new HttpClient(handler) {
        Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)
    };
});
```

Timeout can be adjusted to specific needs.

Cancellation tokens can also be used to help with time management.

Seeing as any exception is just being rethrown, then there is really no need for the try/catch. The exception would be handled by the caller.

`HttpClient` uses an asynchronous API. Its dependents should also be asynchronous all the way through and avoid blocking calls like `.Result` or `.Wait` to avoid deadlocks.

The refactored helper now looks like this

```
/// <summary>
/// Download html from an Internet page.
/// </summary>
public class NetworkHelper {
    static Lazy<HttpClient> httpClient = new Lazy<HttpClient>(() => {
        var handler = CreateHandler();
        return new HttpClient(handler) {
            Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)
        };
    });

    static HttpMessageHandler CreateHandler() {
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        // if the framework supports redirect configuration
        // set max redirect to the desired amount the default is 50
        if (handler.SupportsRedirectConfiguration) {
            handler.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            handler.MaxAutomaticRedirections = 5;
        }
        // if the framework supports automatic decompression 
        // set automatic decompression
        if (handler.SupportsAutomaticDecompression) {
            handler.AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.GZip |
                System.Net.DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        }
        return handler;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the html structure of a site.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="url">Represents the URL of the page where to download the data.</param>
    /// <returns>Return a string that contains the html of the site.</returns>
    public async Task<string> GetHtmlAsync(Uri url, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken)) {
        var response = await httpClient.Value.GetAsync(url, cancellationToken);
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return content;
    }
}
```

And used

```
//...

var client = new NetworkHelper();
var html = await clien.GetHtmlAsync(uri);
```

Comment: I didn't know this `CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken)` was possible with the `CancellationToken` as a parameter :-o

Comment: @Nkosi thanks for the answer, I'll test this in my library. Do you think that 3 seconds are enough for slow server?

Comment: @Charanoglu it was just meant as an example. You can test it with different durations till you get the one you are most comfortable with.

Comment: @Nkosi thanks for clarify this, just a question for download the data should I do something like this: `new NetworkHelper().GetHtmlAsync(coachLink).Result`?

Comment: @Charanoglu that would again be mixing async and blocking calls that can cause deadlock. instead `var html = await new NetworkHelper().GetHtmlAsync(coachLink);`. Other wise you need to use an API that is not asynchronous.